# Creating file with .txt extension (C#)

Tags: c#, io, save

I'm trying to create .txt files with my program and saving the contents of a richtextbox in them (or simply editing existing files, but this already works). The problem is that when I save try saving the file, it creates the file but without the .txt extension. I've tried a couple of things, including the following two, but both create a file without extension. How can I fix this?

```
            SaveFileDialog op = new SaveFileDialog();
            op.Title = "Save";
            op.Filter = "Text Document(*.txt)|*txt";
            //op.DefaultExt = "txt";
            //op.AddExtension = true;

            if (op.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                using (Stream s = File.Open(op.FileName, FileMode.CreateNew))
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(s))
                {
                    sw.Write(richTextBox1.Text);
                }
            }
```

And:

```
   SaveFileDialog op = new SaveFileDialog();
   op.Title = "Save";
   op.Filter = "Text Document(*.txt)|*txt";
   if (op.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
   {
       richTextBox1.SaveFile(op.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
       filename = op.FileName;
       this.Text = op.FileName;
   }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add a dot before the extension here:

```
op.Filter = "Text Document(*.txt)|*txt";
```

So it becomes this:

```
op.Filter = "Text Document(*.txt)|*.txt";
```

Comment: My bad, I overlooked this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a dot:

```
op.Filter = "Text Document(*.txt)|*.txt";
```